# How to check if an added class has a video and then play it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have a jQuery function that removes a class from an element and then add a class to the next element in the list.

```
<div class="slider-slide-wrap has-data multi first-item-is-video shown">
<ul class="multi-items">
  <li class="single-data-item active"></li>
  <li class="single-data-item item-is-video"><video id="video-post">video</video></li>
  <li class="single-data-item item-is-social"></li>
  <li class="single-data-item item-is-social"></li>
  <li class="single-data-item item-is-website"></li>
  <li class="single-data-item item-is-website"></li>
  <li class="single-data-item item-is-video"><video id="video-post">video</video></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The function works by clicking a button and it removes `.active` from the `li` and adds `.active` to the next `li`.

The problem I'm having are the ones with the class `.item-is-video`. Those have video files and when those are selected, they play all videos. I'm trying to find a way to play the video when the button is click so that when `.active` is removed and added to the next `li`, if `.item-is-video` is `.active` then play the video. It either plays all videos or none of them.

My question is that I'm looking for a way to play a video only if `.active` has `.item-is-video` and only that video.

My code:

```js
$('#multi-start-video,#multi-next-item-video').click(function() {
         if($('.first-item-is-video.shown .multi-items li:first-child').is(':visible')) {
           $('#multi-start-video').css('display','none');
           $('#multi-next-item-video').css('display','block');
         } else {
           $('#multi-start-video').css('display','none');
           $('#multi-next-item-video').css('display','block');
         }
         let $item;
         if(!$('.first-item-is-video.shown ul.multi-items li.single-data-item.active').length) {
             $item = $('.first-item-is-video.shown ul.multi-items li.single-data-item').first();
         }
         else {
            $prev = $('.first-item-is-video.shown ul.multi-items li.single-data-item.active');
            $item = $prev.next();
      
            if(!$prev.next().length) {
                $prev.removeClass('active');
                $prev.fadeOut(5);
                return;
            }
      
            $prev.removeClass('active');
            $prev.fadeOut(5);
        }
        if($($item).is('.item-is-video')) {
            $('video#video-post').trigger('play');
        }
      
        $item.addClass('active');
        $item.fadeIn(5);
        });
```

```css
    .single-data-item {display:none}
    video {width:320px;height:auto}
    .single-data-item li {  list-style-type: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="multi-next-item-video" class="button">Next item</button>
        

    <div class="slider-slide-wrap has-data multi first-item-is-video shown">
        <ul class="multi-items">
          <li class="single-data-item active"></li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-video"><video id="video-post" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-720p.mp4"></video></li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-social">item 2</li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-social">item 3</li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-website">item 4</li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-website">item 5</li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-video"><video id="video-post" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4"></video></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to select the video using $item.find().

So only the selected video will play. You can also use `$('video').trigger('pause')` at the beginning of the click to stop every video when you change to the next item.

Edit: `$('video#video-post')` select all video with the id="video-post". So they all play. `.find()` will only select the child of $item.

You can read more about .find() here: https://api.jquery.com/find/

```js
$('#multi-start-video,#multi-next-item-video').click(function() {
         $('video').trigger('pause');
         if($('.first-item-is-video.shown .multi-items li:first-child').is(':visible')) {
           $('#multi-start-video').css('display','none');
           $('#multi-next-item-video').css('display','block');
         } else {
           $('#multi-start-video').css('display','none');
           $('#multi-next-item-video').css('display','block');
         }
         let $item;
         if(!$('.first-item-is-video.shown ul.multi-items li.single-data-item.active').length) {
             $item = $('.first-item-is-video.shown ul.multi-items li.single-data-item').first();
         }
         else {
            $prev = $('.first-item-is-video.shown ul.multi-items li.single-data-item.active');
            $item = $prev.next();
      
            if(!$prev.next().length) {
                $prev.removeClass('active');
                $prev.fadeOut(5);
                return;
            }
      
            $prev.removeClass('active');
            $prev.fadeOut(5);
        }

        
        if($($item).is('.item-is-video')) {
            $item.find('video#video-post').trigger('play');
        }
      
        $item.addClass('active');
        $item.fadeIn(5);
        });
```

```css
    .single-data-item {display:none}
    video {width:320px;height:auto}
    .single-data-item li {  list-style-type: none}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="multi-next-item-video" class="button">Next item</button>
        

    <div class="slider-slide-wrap has-data multi first-item-is-video shown">
        <ul class="multi-items">
          <li class="single-data-item active"></li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-video"><video id="video-post" src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-720p.mp4"></video></li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-social">item 2</li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-social">item 3</li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-website">item 4</li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-website">item 5</li>
          <li class="single-data-item item-is-video"><video id="video-post" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4"></video></li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### #id MUST be Unique

First and foremost, an ***#id MUST be unique***, there are no exceptions to this fundamentally important rule. So change `#video-post` to `#video-post1` and `#video-post2`...better yet just use `.video-post` class on both.

---

## De-referencing jQuery Objects

The `<video>` tag is controlled by the [Video API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Video_and_audio_APIs) which is a plain JavaScript interface. Although jQuery is essentially JavaScript, jQ cannot recognize plain JS methods such as `.play()` or `.pause()`. While using the `.trigger()` method to fire events is feasible, it is a poor substitute for the control that the Video API provides.

In order to use plain JavaScript methods on an element, it must be referenced as a DOM object not a jQuery object. Of course using a plain JS method such as:

```
const active = document.querySelector('.active'); 
let vid = active.querySelector('video');
```

is bloat if you already have:

```
let $vid = $('.active').find('video');
```

Fortunately, there are two simple ways to convert a jQuery object into a DOM object. The term is called de-referencing. Continuing from the example above:

1. bracket notation

   ```
   $vid[0]
   ```
2. `.get()` method

   ```
   $vid.get(0);
   ```

Either one or the other will suffice (they are equivalents).

---

#### Demo

The demo below is simply a streamlined efficient use of jQuery. It is only a suggestion that you follow this code and style:

- less classes
- no ids
- use of `this` keyword
- flow of conditionals
- use of indexed positions
- use of more appropriate jQuery methods
- event delegation
- mutual exclusivity pattern

The list goes on and to go into details on any one of these points steers away from the question. Try the demo, apply as much as you are able to -- to your own code. All details are commented in the demo. Good luck.

```js
/*
The next 3 statements are one time initialization steps
- declare index count
- hide al <li> except the active one
- hide all videos (this is done separately for the FX)
*/
let index = 0;
$('.items li').not('.active').hide();
$('video').hide();

/*
click event is delegated to <nav>
any <button> clicked by user is considered "this" (also e.target)
*/
$('.navbar').on('click', 'button', function(e) {

  // Declare the last <li> index number 
  const last = $('.items li').length - 1;
  //console.log(last);
  /*
  These control statements establish:
  - if the index number increases or decreases by 1
    according to which <button> was clicked
  - to cycle as a bi-directional loop
  Normally I would use ternary for terseness and less
  bloat but I used if/else if/else for readability instead
  */
  if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
    index++
    if (index > last) {
      index = 0;
    }
  } else {
    index--;
    if (index < 0) {
      index = last;
    }
  }
  //console.log(index);
  /*
  The next two statements will hide ALL <li> and <video>
  tags and ensuring that nothing has the .active class.
  NOTE: The last statement is this.pause()
        .pause() is a plain JavaScript method thus does not
        recognize jQuery objects like $(this) so `this`
        keyword must be used instead
  */
  $('.items li').removeClass('active').fadeOut('slow');
  $('video').each(function(i) {
    $(this).slideUp();
    this.pause();
  });

  /*
  Assign the .active class to the <li> at the position 
  designated by current index number
  */
  $('.items li').eq(index).addClass('active');

  /*
  if current active <li> has the .vid class, reveal <li>
  and <video> separately for FX...
  otherwise just reveal the active <li>
  
  NOTE: The statement: vid[0].play();
        .play() is a plain JS method like .pause() and the 
        variable `$vid` references a jQuery object so $vid
        must be de-referenced to be a DOM object that
        .play() will recognize.
        De-referencing a jQ object can be done by:
        - bracket notation: ex. $vid[0]
        or
        - .get() method: ex. $vid.get(0)
        The index number of 0 is required (first reference)
  */
  if ($('.active').hasClass('vid')) {
    let $vid = $('.active').find('video');
    $('.active').fadeIn('fast');
    $vid.slideDown('slow');
    $vid[0].play();
  } else {
    $('.active').fadeIn('slow');
  }

  /*
  There are three actions requested:
  - stop click event from bubbling*
  - prevent any default actions that clicking could
    cause*
  - terminate function
  *the first two above only happen with jQuery
  */
  return false;
});
```

```css
::root,
body {
  font: 400 3vw/1 Arial;
}

.ui {
  max-width: 420px;
  margin: 5vh auto;
}

.navbar {
  text-align: center
}

.items {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0
}

button {
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer
}

.items li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.ico {
  font-size: 2.25rem
}

.ico::before {
  content: attr(data-ico);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

video {
  width: 360px;
  height: auto
}
```

```html
<form class="ui">
  <nav class='navbar'>
    <button class="ico prev" type='button'>⏪</button>
    <button class="ico next" type='button'>⏩</button>
  </nav>
  <ul class="items">
    <li class="ico active" data-ico=''><a href='#/'>Home</a></li>
    <li class='ico' data-ico=''><a href='#/'>Favorites</a></li>
    <li class='ico vid' data-ico=''>
      <video src="https://cdn.plyr.io/static/demo/View_From_A_Blue_Moon_Trailer-720p.mp4"></video>
    </li>
    <li class='ico' data-ico=''><a href='#/'>Top Topics</a></li>
    <li class='ico' data-ico=''><a href='#/'>Hot Topics</a></li>
    <li class='ico vid' data-ico=''>
      <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerBlazes.mp4"></video>
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```